# Start process with low priority Popen

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, psutil

I am looking for a way to start multiple process efficiently with low priority in Windows. I tried :

```
def run(command):
    # command['Program.exe args1 args2','output_file']
    try :
        p = subprocess.Popen(command[0] , stdout = command[1])
        psutil.Process(p.pid).nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)
        p.wait()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise SystemExit
```

The problem is : the low priority is not set immediately. I get some freeze at the beginning. When I look closer in the process window I can see the priority of the application starting at high_priority and switch to low_priority.

I would like to start immediately at low priority or find another way to block the CPU usage (100% right now).

Then I use the run command inside a multiprocessing pool (few second for each run).

```
def safe_run(args):
    """Call run(), catch exceptions."""
    try: 
        run(args)
    except Exception as e:
        print(args[0])
        print(e)


def parallel(commands,nb_proc):
    # populate files
    # start processes
    if len(commands) < 10:
        nb_proc = 1
    print('Use of {} cpus\n'.format(nb_proc))
    pool = mp.Pool(nb_proc)
    pool.map(safe_run, commands, chunksize=1)
```

**UPDATE**

Test.exe is a fortran code :

```
    integer function NumArguments()
        integer :: IARGC
        NumArguments = IARGC()
    end function

    subroutine GetArgument(Idx,Argument)
      integer, intent(in) :: Idx
      character(LEN=*), intent(out) :: Argument
      call GETARG(Idx,Argument)
   end subroutine

    program Console
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: INTEG = SELECTED_INT_KIND(9)
    integer(INTEG), parameter :: MAX_STRING_LEN = 1024_INTEG
    character(LEN=MAX_STRING_LEN) :: FileName
    integer(INTEG) :: i


    call GetArgument(1,FileName)

    ! Body of Console
    !print *, 'Hello World'
    !print *, FileName

    call sleep(5)
    open(unit=1, file=FileName,status='new')
     Do i=1,1000,1
         write(1,*) i
     Enddo
     close(unit=1)

    end program Console
```

Full code :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""

"""

###############################################################################
###############################################################################
#
#                     IMPORT & INIT                 
# 
###############################################################################
###############################################################################
import psutil
import subprocess
import time
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp
import os

TEST_EXE  = "Console.exe"
nb_proc      =   4



###############################################################################
###############################################################################
#
#                     FUNCTION                 
# 
###############################################################################
###############################################################################

def run(command):
    try :
        print(command[0])
        psutil.Process().nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS) # lower priority
        p = subprocess.Popen(command[0] , stdout = command[1])
        psutil.Process().nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS) # lower priority
        p.wait()
    except:
        print('Point {} fail'.format(point))
        raise SystemExit

def safe_run(args):
    """Call run(), catch exceptions."""
    try: 
        run(args)
    except Exception as e:
        print('{} error'.format(args[0]))


def parallel(commands,nb_proc):
    print('Use of {} cpus\n'.format(nb_proc))
    pool = mp.Pool(nb_proc) 
    pool.map(safe_run, commands, chunksize=1)


###############################################################################
###############################################################################
#
#                     MAIN SCRIPT                 
# 
###############################################################################
###############################################################################

current_dir = os.path.abspath('')
print('\nCurrent directory {}'.format(current_dir))  
t1 = time.time()

logfiles = list()        
commands = list()
logfiles_obj = list()
for step in range(100):
    logfile = open(os.path.join(current_dir,'logfile_'+ str(step) + '.out'), 'w')
    args = TEST_EXE + ' ' + os.path.join(current_dir,'output_'+str(step) + '.txt')
    temp = (args,logfile)
    commands.append(temp)

# run in parallel
print("Calculation running ...\n")
parallel(commands,nb_proc)


for log in logfiles_obj:
    log.close()

# time for running all the point and complete
t2 = time.time()
print ("\n ########## Overall time : %5.2f secondes ##########" %(t2 - t1))
print("\n ##########       Correct ending       ##########")
```

Answer (score 11):

The normal way on a Posix system would be to use the `preexec_fn` parameter of `subprocess.Popen` to call a function before starting the command (detailed lower in this answer). Unfortunately this is intended to occur between the `fork` and `exec` system calls and Windows do not create processes that way.

On Windows, the underlying (WinAPI) system call used to create sub-processes is [`CreateProcess`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The page on MSDN says:

> ```
> BOOL WINAPI CreateProcess(
>   ...
>   _In_        DWORD                 dwCreationFlags,
>   ...
> );
> ```
>
> dwCreationFlags [in] 
>   The flags that control the priority class and the creation of the process... 
>   This parameter also controls the new process's priority class, which is used to determine the scheduling priorities of the process's threads.

Unfortunately, the Python interface has no provision for setting the child priority, because it is explicitely being said:

> creationflags, if given, can be CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE or REATE_NEW_PROCESS_GROUP. (Windows only)

But the documentation for `dwCreationFlags` on the MSDN also says:

> ... If none of the priority class flags is specified, the priority class defaults to NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS **unless the priority class of the creating process is IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS or BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS**. In this case, **the child process receives the default priority class of the calling process**.

That means that the priority can simply be inherited, to the Windows way of controlling the child priority from Python is to set the priority before starting the subprocess, and reset it immediately after:

```
def run(command):
    # command['Program.exe args1 args2','output_file']
    try :
        psutil.Process().nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS) # lower priority
        p = subprocess.Popen(command[0] , stdout = command[1])    # start child at low priority
        psutil.Process().nice(psutil.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)  # reset current priority
        p.wait()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise SystemExit
```

---

Remaining part of this answer would be relevant on a Posix system like Linux or Unix.

The `preexec_fn` parameter of `Popen` is what you need. It allows to call a callable object (for example a function) between the creation of the child process and the execution of the command. You could do:

```
def set_low_pri():
    psutil.Process().nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)
```

and then use it to start a child at a low priority:

```
def run(command):
    # command['Program.exe args1 args2','output_file']
    try :
        p = subprocess.Popen(command[0] , stdout = command[1], preexec_fn=set_low_pri)
        p.wait()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        raise SystemExit
```

That way, Python ensures that the low priority is set **before** your command is executed.

---

Ref.: the documentation for the subprocess module states:

> 17.5.1.2. Popen Constructor
>   
> ...
>
> ```
> class subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize=-1, executable=None, stdin=None, stdout=None,
>       stderr=None, preexec_fn=None, close_fds=True, shell=False, cwd=None, env=None,
>       universal_newlines=False, startupinfo=None, creationflags=0, restore_signals=True,
>       start_new_session=False, pass_fds=(), *, encoding=None, errors=None)
> ```
>
> ...
> If preexec_fn is set to a callable object, this object will be called in the child process just before the child is executed. (POSIX only)

---

But the above method is not thread safe! If two threads run concurrently, we could get into the following race condition:

- thread A lowers priority
- thread A starts it child (at low priority)
- thread B lowers priority (a no-op)
- thread A resets normal priority
- thread B starts its child **at normal priority**
- thread B resets normal priority (a no-op)

The problem is that `multiprocessing.dummy` is a wrapper around `threading`. The Standard Python Library documentation (3.6) says in 17.2.2.13. The multiprocessing.dummy module

> multiprocessing.dummy replicates the API of multiprocessing but is no more than a wrapper around the threading module.

Once the problem is identified, the fix is trivial: just use a `Lock` to protect the critical section:

```
lock = mp.Lock()

def run(command):
    try :
        print(command[0])
        lock.acquire()
        psutil.Process().nice(psutil.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS) # lower priority
        p = subprocess.Popen(command[0] , stdout = command[1])
        psutil.Process().nice(psutil.NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS) # normal priority
        lock.release()
        p.wait()
    except:
        print('Point {} fail'.format(point))
        raise SystemExit
```

Comment: I agree but I work on Windows. "preexec_fn" is an Unix command right ?

Comment: @Coolpix: I had not noticed the Windows part in your question (I should have read it more carefuly...). But I have edited my answer with a Windows way.

Comment: No problem ! Thanks for your answer. Its seems to work at the beginning the process is starting in low priority. But I don't know why "Program.exe" return to high priorty :/

Comment: @Coolpix: I could not reproduce that last behaviour. In my tests I was able to start a new process at low priority and then reset the parent process priority to normal, and the child keeps its low priority. I'm afraid I cannot investigate further without a [mcve].

Comment: @Coolpix: I had a mistake in my previous code: I reset the priority of the child instead of the parent one :-( . It should be better now...

Comment: I added a complete and verfiable exemple in my first post ! :)

Comment: @Coolpix: The complet code allowed me to reproduce, understand and fix! The problem is caused by multiprocessing.dummy being a wrapper around the threading module. My initial `run` function is not thread safe, so it needs synchronization in a multi-thread context. See my last edit.

Answer (score 7):

surprised no-one has suggested it, but just because the subprocessing module doesn't expose the constants needed, doesn't mean we can't pass them to the module to set the priority:

```
import subprocess

ABOVE_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00008000
BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS = 0x00004000
HIGH_PRIORITY_CLASS         = 0x00000080
IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS         = 0x00000040
NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS       = 0x00000020
REALTIME_PRIORITY_CLASS     = 0x00000100

p = subprocess.Popen(["notepad.exe"], creationflags=BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS)

p.wait()
```

this sets the creation flags correctly and starts the process with the set priority, to properly expose it the _winapi and subprocessing modules would both need to be patched (to make the constants part of the module rather than the sketch)

Comment: just as a note, I've submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/4150) to make the required changes to the two files mentioned, so this may end up included in mainline python sooner or later.

Comment: I didn't know we could do this. But this doesn't work as expected. The process is launch at low priority and then return to high priority. I guess its because the method is not thread safe (Serge Ballesta answer below)

Comment: for future reference, this has now been merged into python for a future release: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/b5d9e0811463f3b28ba355a9e0bee7f1682854e3 probably python 3.7

Answer (score 3):

With Python 3.7, this is available for Windows (but not Posix):

```
startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
startupinfo.dwFlags |= subprocess.BELOW_NORMAL_PRIORITY_CLASS
subprocess.Popen(command, startupinfo=startupinfo)
```

for Linux:

```
subprocess.Popen(command, preexec_fn=lambda : os.nice(10))
```

Answer (score 1):

or, for Linux, just prepend a command with 'nice -n 10'.

subprocess.Popen(['nice','-n','10', 'command','arg'])